# Column values are getting cleared while sorting in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

MY JqGrid is being created properly. But when I am sorting any column by clicking on column name, Timer column gets empty and no values are being displayed in timer column. Here is the code, I am using.

```
function getData(){
$.getJSON(fetch_url).done(
    function(root) {
    var dataJson = JSON.stringify(root.records);
    $("#engGrid").jqGrid({
        datatype : "jsonstring",
        datastr : dataJson,
        caption : "Cases",
        colNames : ['Case No', 'Timer'],
        colModel : [ {
                name : 'CASENUMBER',
                index : 'CASENUMBER',
                width : 75,
                align : 'center'
            },
            {
                name : 'TIME_MINS',
                index : 'TIME_MINS',
                width : 90,
                formatter : TimeColor
            }
        ]
    });
});
}

function TimeColor(cellval, option, rowdata) {
     return minToHourConversion(cellval);
}

function minToHourConversion(minutes){
    var timeString;
    if(minutes>=60){
        timeString=Math.floor(minutes/60)+" hrs "+ (minutes%60)+" mins";
    }
    else {
        timeString= minutes + " mins";
    }
    return timeString;
}
```

Comment: But you forgot to ask your question.

Comment: I asked it. While sorting any column, Timer column becomes empty. why? ON sort also, timer values should be displayed.